# C# WebBrowser Control Masked ListBox

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to create a program that will programmatically complete a form.

The payee field on the form uses a searchable listbox.

I'm using the code below to place the text in the drop down box, but it's not activating it as though it was searched and selected from the list.

```
webBrowserWB.Document.GetElementById("select2-chosen-4").InnerText = payee;
```

How would I mimic key strokes to type the value that I need placed in that field?  Or is there another option?

Example of the list box is in the image below.  Values don't appear until the user begins typing in the field.

[image: Masked ListBox]

Edited to include HTML

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox
select2-drop-active" id="select2-drop" style="display: block; left: 
6.5px; width: 781px; top: 240px; bottom: auto;">   
    <div class="select2-search">       
        <label for="s2id_autogen4_search" class="select2-
        offscreen">Payee</label> 
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" 
        autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" 
        role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-
        owns="select2-results-4"id="s2id_autogen4_search" placeholder="">   
    </div>   
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-4"><li 
class="select2-no-results"></li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Need to include relevant Html part in your question. What it looks like a dropdown might be a number of things.

Comment: Edited to include html

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see **id** named `select2-chosen-4` in your html code !

Comment: The id changes when the drop down is clicked.  The id that I use in c# is when the page loads. The id in the code above is when the search drop down is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the WebBrowser control, I was able to resolve my issue by using Selenium.